# Can minors receive payments from class action lawsuits?

Tags: united-states, minor, litigation, class-action

If a minor is included in the class of a class action lawsuit, and the plaintiffs win or the defendant settles, can the minor receive payment?

The suit was filed in California (the GitHub Copilot suit), and the minor (me) lives in Oregon. I have already contacted the legal team; I'm just curious to find out before they answer whether it's likely I'll be able to receive payment.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus please do not answer in comments.